# Splitting textfile at whitespace

Tags: java, file, split, java.util.scanner, delimiter

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("textfile.txt");
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i =0 ; sc.hasNextLine(); i++)
{
    String temp = sc.nextLine();
    tokens.add(temp);
}
```

My textfile looks something like

```
A
B
C
*empty line* 
D
E
F
*empty line*
```

and so on..

The trouble I'm having is I'm trying to store each section to an array (including the empty line), but I don't know how to go about splitting up these sections. By section I mean A B C *empty line*, is one section.

Comment: So you want to split on an empty line and also want this empty line to be saved as part of each group? Also, when you say empty line, do you mean no characters or a line with only white spaces?

Comment: From what it looks like - No characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just splitting it at new lines and not white spaces, which is what it seems to be since you are using `hasNextLine()` and `nexLine()`, you can try this.

```
final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt"));
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    //Read the next line
    String temp = sc.nextLine();
    builder.append(temp);

    if(temp.trim().equals("")) {
        tokens.add(builder.toString() + NEW_LINE);  //Copy the gotten tokens to the list adding a new line since we read up to, not including, the new line
        builder = new StringBuilder();  //Clear the builder
    }
}
//Copy any remaining characters to the list
tokens.add(builder.toString() + NEW_LINE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding every line to list as you read from file,
append to string builder or temporary string. When you detect new line, after appending it to temporary string or string builder, add all you got so far into list. Repeat until you have lines.

Comment: Hmm that sounds good, but I tried coding that and didn't get very far.  String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  
  for (int i =0 ; sc.hasNextLine(); i++)
  {
  
  if(sc.equals(newline)) { 
   //add all 
  }
  
  
  }

Comment: Can you post where did you get ?

Comment: I cannot code on my smartphone duh. Store sc.nextLine into temporary String current line. Append current line to String builder. If { current line equlas new line operator, add stringbuilder.toString() to list. Reset String builder by nulling it.

Comment: Here is what I got so far - but it didn't seem to append anything to the empty list.  for (int i =0 ; sc.hasNextLine(); i++)
  {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
   sb.append(currentLine);
   if(currentLine == newline) { 
   tokens.add(sb.toString());
  }
   sb = null;
  }

Answer (score 0):

See complete example as asked Originally :

```
package com.raj;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Scanner sc 
= new Scanner(new File("textfile.txt"));
List<StringBuilder> tokens 
= new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
StringBuilder builder 
= new StringBuilder();

boolean saveFlag = true;


while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
String temp = sc.nextLine();

if (temp.isEmpty()) {
tokens.add(builder);
builder = new StringBuilder();
saveFlag = false;
continue;
}

builder.append(temp + "\n");
saveFlag = true;
}
sc.close();

if (saveFlag) tokens.add(builder);

for (StringBuilder sb : tokens) {
System.out.println(sb);
}

}
}
```